# Can I use a rechargable battery with a PIR sensor designed to use two CR2032 batteries?

Tags: batteries, lifepo4

I use a PIR sensor that works with two CR2032 3v button batteries (in parallel).

The main problem I face is that the batteries are only lasting for less than one month.

```
Input voltage: 3V
Cut-off voltage: 1.33V
Quiescent current: 3.5mA
Current when triggering: 4.5mA for <200ms (need to quantify exactly for how long)
Peak current when triggering: 25mA for <200ms (need to quantify exactly how often and for how long since it occurs in some sparse occasions only, specially during the first 5 minutes)
```

I would like to replace those weak batteries with a nice rechargable one.

My idea would be to use a LiFePO4 3.2 V 400 mAh and simply connect its - and + in place of one of the two CR2032.

Since I am not an expert I would like to ask here before taking action.

Is mine a good and fairly safe choice?

Comment: Not realistically, no.  Questions about consumer products are off topic here.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton and thanks for your input.
I've changed the question in order to respect the requirement.

Comment: Based on the very limited information you have provided, the answer is no. You have a device that expects 3V and a battery that will provide a higher voltage. There is no evidence that your device will survive the higher voltage.

Comment: Are the specs that you've posted for the device? No wonder the CR2032s aren't lasting very long; those are very high quiescent and peak currents for those types of cells. They are designed to provide on the order of uA usually. Might be able to help more if we knew more about the PIR sensor or what specifically the batteries are connected to.

Comment: It is a commercial product but I was asked to remove its name from my question because of site rules... How can I get useful data in order to improve my question?

Comment: It is a motion sensor that communicates via zigbee to a gateway in order to turn lights on / off